# Sending a list over a network in java

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

here is my list:

```
List<Form> to_be_sent=new ArrayList<Form>();
```

Form is a class that implements serializable and only contains string fields. 
Can I do this :

```
ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
writer.writeObject(to_be_sent);
writer.close();
```

Comment: make ByteArrayOutputStream and try. Should work.

Comment: @Jochen : I wanted to confirm before trying it. Many changes will have to be made to try it out.

Comment: @tigran : I wanted to send the objects as such, Since list also implements serializable.

Comment: You just need to write some test code, a few lines will do. and you will have your answer. Something that you can turn into bytes, can be transfered over network.

Comment: @MarkByers : Trying it will mean making a lot of changes in the project. I don't want to try it out without being sure. Before this we used to send it as just string .The string construction was done in a for loop.

Comment: @Neevek : Please answer if you know it. I wouldn't have asked if I was in a position to try it out.

Comment: Try testing this outside your project. That way you won't have to make all the changes in your project before knowing if it works.

Comment: Well, what about writing a small test case with a list of classes that contain string field? Serialize them to a file and read them back. If that works sending the data over a network should work, too. There's no need to do a first test in the project itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!

Here's a minimal, working implementation that serializes a List, and sends it over a socket connection and deserializes it at the other end, printing what arrived.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream in = new ServerSocket(999).accept().getInputStream();
                Object object = new ObjectInputStream(in).readObject();
                System.out.println(object.getClass() + ": " + object);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    serverThread.start();
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 999);
    new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).writeObject(list);
    serverThread.join();
}
```

Output:

```
class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList: [one, two, three]
```

Comment: Yes it works. The whole list array is being serialized and sent over the network:)